# Working configuration for Seaside Rest with current Pharo Build (5.0

Tags: rest, pharo, seaside

I am desperately trying to install Seaside Rest in Pharo 5. Is it recommended, or should I go back to Pharo 4?
What I have done so far:

- There is a Configuration called SeasideRest -> does not work / no ServerAdaptor
- I have also tried (with a clean image)
  `ConfigurationOfSeaside3 project stableVersion load: 'REST'`

`ConfigurationOfSeaside project stableVersion load`does not load the REST part.

Any ideas?

Regards

Max

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ConfigurationOfSeasideRest` is only for Seaside 3.0.x.
Since Seaside 3.1, the REST group is included in the main configuration `ConfigurationOfSeaside3`.

Since this should work fine in Pharo 5, I suspect that you are hitting a Metacello issue. The recommended way to load any configuration with Metacello is with the new API:

```
Metacello new
   configuration:'Seaside3';
   repository: 'http://www.smalltalkhub.com/mc/Seaside/MetacelloConfigurations/main';
   version: #stable;
  load: #('REST')
```

Comment: This configuration is missing the Zinc-Seaside. I am currently trying to use #46. Will keep you updated.